# UIPanGestureRecognizer not working with UIControlEvents

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, draggable, target, uipangesturerecognizer

I made a custom UIControl which uses `UIControlEvents` to recognize certain interactions. It worked all just fine. Now I also want my UIControl to recognize a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, here's the code

```
fieldView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(willSelectField(sender:)), for: .touchDown)
fieldView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didSelectField(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
fieldView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(canceledFieldSelection(sender:)), for: .touchUpOutside)
fieldView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggingField(gesture:))))
```

So when I click on my *fieldView* (custom UIControl) `touchDown` will be recognized. If I do not start panning, `touchUpInside` and `touchUpOutside`will also be recognized. But if I pan and for example let go outside my *fieldView*, `touchUpOutside` won't get triggered.

---

**NOTE:** `touchDragInside` is not an alternative because it only recognizes dragging inside a range of about 100px.

Answer (score 1):

See the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer):

> If a gesture recognizer recognizes its gesture, the remaining touches for the view are cancelled.

You can try to set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `false`, or override `touchesCancelled(_:with:)` in your views.

Comment: I tried it but the `touchesCancelled` method won't get called and I also can't find a way to differentiate in this methods between `touchUpInside` or `touchUpOutside`

Comment: Adding cancelsTouchesInView worked for me. I have a UIControl subclass and am using UIPanGesture/UILongPressGesture combo to drive sendAction(...). I set that property on both GRs